# How can I upload a picture in couch db and retrieve it

Tags: couchdb

i am working on Couch DB ,i want to create a user profile after user signs up for my website.
During registration,the user uploads his image and then it is added to that user's document in Couch Db and retrieved so that all his details along with his image are displayed as his profile.

Answer (score 2):

You can store a picture as an attachment, either in the user's profile, or, in preference, to a separate database. Here's uploading a single attachment to a new document:

```
curl -vXPUT $COUCH/testy/doc/attached-jpg --data-binary ~/tmp/swirl/docs/test/data/m74.jpg
```

Obviously if you're updating an existing document you'll need to provide `_rev` fields appropriately.

Typically the user profile is kept lean and the profile images are handled from a separate db which then doesn't require caching that in RAM on the server if not needed. A validation function can be used to ensure that the only user who updates a profile picture is the owning user.